# Проблема c перетаскиванием окна и методом close() и showMinimized() PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Решил сделать окно без обычных кнопок windows (свернуть **`-`**, закрыть **`Х`**).
Сделал две круглые кнопки, на одну добавил функцию "закрыть", а на вторую функцию "свернуть".

Функции работают, но можно ли сделать так, чтобы не надо было кликать два раза чтобы свернуть и закрыть.

И еще нашел проблему с перетаскиванием окна, его нельзя перетаскивать.

**open.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from untitled import Ui_MainWindow


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Close)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.Minimize)


    def Close(self):
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def Minimize(self):
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.showMinimized)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**untitled.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1100, 460)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1074, 7, 16, 16))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 7px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 0, 4);")
        self.pushButton.setText("")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1101, 31))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(65, 65, 65);")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1049, 7, 16, 16))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 183, 0);\n"
"border-radius: 7px;")
        self.pushButton_2.setText("")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label.raise_()
        self.pushButton.raise_()
        self.pushButton_2.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#from untitled import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1100, 460)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1074, 7, 16, 16))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 7px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 0, 4);")
        self.pushButton.setText("")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1101, 31))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(65, 65, 65);")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1049, 7, 16, 16))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 183, 0);\n"
"border-radius: 7px;")
        self.pushButton_2.setText("")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label.raise_()
        self.pushButton.raise_()
        self.pushButton_2.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.myClose)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.myMinimize)

        self.start = QPoint(0, 0)    # +                  
        self.pressing = False        # +


    def myClose(self):
#        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.close()

    def myMinimize(self):
#        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.showMinimized)
        self.showMinimized()     

# + vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
        self.pressing = True

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.pressing:
            self.end = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
            self.movement = self.end-self.start
            self.setGeometry(self.mapToGlobal(self.movement).x(),
                                self.mapToGlobal(self.movement).y(),
                                self.width(),
                                self.height())
            self.start = self.end

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.pressing = False
# + ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```